# VGG on the gcp ml-engine is very slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have a model on the google cloud ml-engine, basically consisting of a keras implementation of the VGG19 neural network (even without the fully-connected layers on the top). More precisely, the image is first resized using `tf.image.resize_images`, and then passed through the VGG with mean feature activations computed in 5 different layers.

When running it from the terminal as

```
gcloud ml-engine predict \
    --model Features \
    --version v1 \
    --json-instances \
    test_image.json
```

the entire execution time is roughly 17-18 seconds (not on the first run).

That seems to be much slower than a single run through the VGG should take, do you have any ideas as to what might be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed the model with all of the default settings, you will get single core machines, which can be fairly slow for deep models.

We have various other offerings in alpha and beta stages (including GPUs very soon); please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com to request access if you would like access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

We sent an email as you suggested, but haven't got a reply yet. Meanwhile, could you please tell from your experience, approximately how much time a single pass of an image (say, 512x512) through the VGG (deployed as a ml-engine model) should take?